# What's the usage of the reference voltage in voltage-referenced I/O standards?

Tags: voltage-reference

In FPGA I/O resource user guides, there are many places mentioning the "reference voltage" in different IO standards, and how the IO bank can provide such reference voltage to meet the standard requirement. There is also a term "Voltage-referenced I/O standards" to collectively refer those I/O standards requiring a reference voltage.

My question is, however, not related to FPGA device, but a basic one for understanding of the purpose of the reference voltage in those I/O standards, or at lease one example I/O standard.

I was not able to locate such info by searching the web. They all talk about how to provide the reference voltage, but not about why the Vref is needed in the first place, or how it's used.

Thanks.

Update: the following is a diagram take from xilinx ug471. There is a Vref in the diagram.

[image]

Comment: Please provide examples. In general, I/Os are referenced to a supply voltage.